# angular ui-grid sort icons do not display correctly

Tags: javascript, html, css, angularjs, angular-ui-grid

I've already researched and tried placing all the font files (ui-grid.eot, ui-grid.svg, ui-grid.ttf, ui-grid.woff) in the same directory as ui-grid-unstable.css. No matter what I do, the Korean looking characters still appear!

Also in firefox I get

> downloadable font: download failed (font-family: "ui-grid" style:normal weight:normal stretch:normal src index:1): status=2147500037
>   source: file:///C:/webapp/css/lib/angular/css/ui-grid.woff app.css
>   downloadable font: download failed (font-family: "ui-grid" style:normal weight:normal stretch:normal src index:2): status=2147500037
>   source: file:///C:/webapp/css/lib/angular/css/ui-grid.ttf

I also don't use any sort of build mechanism ( bower etc.)

Is there any way to get the icons to display properly? Or like some sort of workaround

`---mainDir
    --css
        --app.css
    --images
    --js
        --controllers
            --controller1.js
            -controller2.js
            etc.
        --services
            --app.js
            etc
    --lib
        --angular
            --css
                --ui-grid.eot
                --ui-grid.svg
                --ui-grid.ttf
                --ui-grid.woff
                --ui-grid-unstable.css
            --js
                --angular.min.js
                --angular-route.min.js
                --ui-grid-unstable.js
        --bootstrap
            -css
            -fonts
            -js
        --jquery
            -js
    --views
        --view1.html
        --view2.html
        etc.
    index.html`

Comment: Any way you can provide a screenshot of what your file structure looks like?

Comment: edited for file structure

Comment: Do me a favor, steal the ui-grid-unstable.js in the js folder and put in in your css folder with all the other files (eot,svg, etc). Adjust the ui-grid-unstable.js reference so it's correct and try it.

Comment: actually tried that and it still didn't work :(

Comment: http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/82011/angular-ui-grid-sort-icons

Comment: RESOLVED WEEEEEEEEEE. Turns out the problem was specific to the ui-grid-unstable.css version. Referenced the latest by using <link href="http://ui-grid.info/release/ui-grid-unstable.css" rel="stylesheet"> and it worked!

Comment: Post that as an answer and accept you own after the time limit. That way people can see it when they look at this question in the future. Grats dude.

Comment: actually.....tried to copy and paste the same stuff from the external reference url into my local css.. and it doesn't work. do u know what may be the cause of that?

Comment: Something in the way you are referencing that local file would have to be off. Mainly just speculating at this point.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Turns out the problem was specific to the ui-grid-unstable.css version. Referenced the latest by using

```
<link href="http://ui-grid.info/release/ui-grid-unstable.css" rel="stylesheet">
```

and it worked!

Strangely, if I copy and paste the code from that link and paste it in my local ui-grid-unstable.css, the characters are still the korean-looking ones...

Answer (score 1):

A nice and working solution is to replace the code in `css` file like this:

```
.ui-grid-icon-down-dir:before {
  content: '\25bc';
}
.ui-grid-icon-up-dir:before {
  content: '\25b2';
}
```

The original content `'\c358'` and `'\c359'` will display the korean-looking ones in IE.

Answer (score 0):

font uri path not found in your project.follow the folder structure as same in git. if you still face same problem use updated angular ui grid version.
custom column header template is another way to resolve the sort icon problem.
This is default header template code:

```
 <div ng-class="{ 'sortable': sortable }">

  <div class="ui-grid-cell-contents" col-index="renderIndex" title="TOOLTIP">
    <span>{{ col.displayName CUSTOM_FILTERS }}</span>

    <span ui-grid-visible="col.sort.direction" ng-class="{ 'ui-grid-icon-up-dir': col.sort.direction == asc, 'ui-grid-icon-down-dir': col.sort.direction == desc, 'ui-grid-icon-blank': !col.sort.direction }">
      &nbsp;
    </span>
  </div>

  <div class="ui-grid-column-menu-button" ng-if="grid.options.enableColumnMenus && !col.isRowHeader  && col.colDef.enableColumnMenu !== false" ng-click="toggleMenu($event)" ng-class="{'ui-grid-column-menu-button-last-col': isLastCol}">
    <i class="ui-grid-icon-angle-down">&nbsp;</i>
  </div>

  <div ui-grid-filter></div>
</div>
```

From default template just replace your own css class by 'ui-grid-icon-up-dir' for up icon and 'ui-grid-icon-down-dir' for down icon.

Answer (score 0):

You need to go to the version folder, download the following files :

- **ui-grid.eot**
- **ui-grid.svg**
- **ui-grid.ttf**
- **ui-grid.woff**

and place in the same local folder where ui-grid.css file is stored.

e.g. if you are using ui-grid.js and ui-grid.css version 4.0.4 you will need to download the above mentioned files from

https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-grid.info/tree/gh-pages/release/4.0.4

and place in the same local folder where ui-grid.css file is stored. You don't need to reference these 4 files in your code explicitly.
Hope this helps.